# Why is this <hr> (horizontal rule) appearing above the table instead of below it?

Tags: html, html-table

When I display the following HTML in Chrome or Safari, the `<hr>` causes a horizontal rule to be draw above the table, but I would like the horizontal rule to appear below the table.  That is why I put the `<hr>` tag *after* the table stuff and not before it. You can try it for yourself.  What do I not understand?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            .centerbox {
                /* basic styling */
                width: 260px;
                height: 380px;
                font-size: 12px;
                border: 2px solid #555;
                background : #FFD;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Onora</title>
</head>

    <body>
        <div class="centerbox">
            <table width="100%" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Welcome, Stranger</td>
                    <td align="right">logout</td>
                </tr
            </table>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't close your `tr`. And `<hr>` should be `<hr />`

Comment: Thanks. Wow, I'm dense.  What would I do without StackOverflow?

Comment: @ldiqual, no, it **should not** be `<hr />`. But `<meta ... />` should be `<meta ...>`. (This is HTML, not XHTML.)

Comment: Adding to @bfrohs : http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element

Comment: In HTML5 (HTML serialization) the `/` is optional for void elements. Both with and without are OK. But I recommend consistency within a single HTML document.

Comment: As it's optional in HTML5 but required in XHTML, I prefer to put it to make my code compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion -- I'm learning a bit about HTML5 here as well.

Answer (score 2):

Close your `tr`. Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nc6Tx/) for a demo.